# how to remove separator in group_concat in mysql

Tags: mysql

In mysql query am using grpup_concat function to concatenate the rows. It resulting the correct values but it is adding separator.
for ex: my result for specified column as below.

`{10,20}|,{20,30}|,{40,50}`    // pipe symbol i have added as a separator but it is again adding comma as a separator.

desired result:  {10,20}|{20,30}|{40,50}

let me know how to remove the separator. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try a : GROUP_CONCAT(split(field, ","), '|')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whatever you need as s separator, specify after SEPARATOR keyword just like below:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field_name SEPARATOR '|') FROM table_name`